# Missing python library in Bitnami Odoo Stack

Tags: odoo, bitnami

I have a trouble installing an Odoo Third Party App. I have the integrated package of Bitnami Odoo Stack.

In clear, I want to install the following module https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/13.0/zoom_integration/, the matter is that when I am trying to install it I find the following problem:  Python library not installed: zoomus.

I cannot find the python cmd shell in Bitnami Odoo Stack in which I should execute pip install zoomus. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami Software Engineer here,

Use these commands:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/use_odoo
pip install zoomus
```

The first command will load the environment variables to use the right `pip` path.

Comment: I am using the stack in windows where it does not exist a directory shuch like that.

Comment: Then, open `use_odoo.bat` on your installation directory and execute `pip install zoomus`.