# How to install pandas in bitnami odoo on AWS EC2?

Tags: odoo, bitnami

There is a module that needs to be installed in Odoo but it is dependent on the panda library. Odoo is running on AWS EC2 (packaged by bitnami). How do I install this dependency in the stack instead of in the machine? The OS is Debian 11.9.

Tried using the answer here ([Missing python library in Bitnami Odoo Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66674313/missing-python-library-in-bitnami-odoo-stack)) but I got sudo: /opt/bitnami/use_odoo: command not found.

Comment: Solved it, cd into /opt/bitnami, then run pip install pandas (no need to add use_odoo)

Comment: Please answer your own question and mark as solved, not only in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, cd into `/opt/bitnami`, then run `pip install pandas` (no need to add use_`odoo`) –